# How do I verify the Tor Circuit duration?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit, guard-node

I'm thinking of having JavaScript code send messages to my server. How do I go about it? Is there a better way?
Edit: How do I find out the exact duration for which a Tor circuit exists before changing?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Better than what for what?